# Unable to Run Sonar Scan

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Testing with a basic hello world class and cannot get past this error. The only class it is analyzing is a simple HelloWorld class. Currently using my company's sonar instance, last resort will install a local instance to test with.

Other instances of this issue online discuss a version issue but I think I am up to date. I'm not sure where all the plugin versions come from but no one else in the company has this issue so I figure it must be local somehow.
Happy to provide any extra details.

Error

```
[ERROR] Unable to create symbol table for : /Users/me/dev/tester/src/main/java/com/mc/test/HelloWorld.java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170) ~[asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153) ~[asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424) ~[asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.loadClass(BytecodeCompleter.java:220) ~[java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbols.<init>(Symbols.java:176) ~[java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:55) ~[java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:105) ~[java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84) [java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67) [java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:114) [java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:108) [java-frontend-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:87) [sonar-java-plugin-4.5.0.8398.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62) [sonar-scanner-api-batch9011538681698632830.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60) [sonar-scanner-api-2.6.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.execute(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240) [sonar-scanner-api-2.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151) [sonar-scanner-api-2.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78) [sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112) [sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105) [maven-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:954) [maven-embedder-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) [maven-embedder-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192) [maven-embedder-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:na]
```

Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mc.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>tester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/*.xml</sonar.exclusions>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/models/*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonar.company.com</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.scm.disabled>true</sonar.scm.disabled>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Class

```
package com.mc.test;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Relevant versions

```
[INFO] Download sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.7.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-github-plugin-1.4.0.699.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-python-plugin-1.7.0.1195.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-pmd-plugin-2.6.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-android-plugin-1.1.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.4.0.522.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-javascript-plugin-2.20.0.4207.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-csharp-plugin-5.7.0.612.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.4.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-java-plugin-4.5.0.8398.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-ldap-plugin-2.1.0.507.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-web-plugin-2.5.0.476.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-pitest-plugin-0.7.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-typescript-plugin-1.1.0.1079.jar
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.6.7
```

Comment: Are you using Java 9? Do you see any warning like this in log `WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred`?

Comment: Yes! I actually just thought to check and actually maven is using Java 10! I'm going to try and make it use 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My JAVA_HOME was set to use Java10, forcing maven to use Java8 resolved the issue.